# Wxpython - TextCtrl questions/weird copy "bug" (?)

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a weird problem. I can only copy the text once. If I press clear and type again the text disappears and I have to restart it. Where have I messed up?

Now the questions:

1) Can I bind the clear function to the "Encrypt/Decrypt" so that each time I want to type again it 
clears automatically?

2)How can I copy the output to the clipboard with a button?

Code(Pretty messy):

```
import wx

class main(wx.Frame):



    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Title',size=(353,270))

        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)

        button1=wx.Button(self.panel,label='Encrypt\Decrypt',pos=(10,10),size=(-1,60))
        button2=wx.Button(self.panel,label='Current PIN',        pos=(150,10),size=(-1,60))
        button3=wx.Button(self.panel,label='Change PIN',           pos=(250,10),size=(-1,60))
        button4= wx.Button(self.panel,label='Reset',pos=(10,200),size=(-1,20))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.option1, button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.option2, button2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.option3, button3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clear,  button4)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.closewindow)
        self.pin='ABC'

    def option1(self,event):
        box1=wx.TextEntryDialog(None,'Type...','','...here')
        if box1.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            answer1=box1.GetValue()

        def xor(text, key):
            list = ''
            for char in text:
                for ch in key:
                    char = chr(ord(char) ^ ord(ch))
                list += char
            return list

        msg = xor(answer1, self.pin)
        self.output=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1,msg,pos=(10,80),size=(300, 100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        #output=wx.StaticText(self.panel,-1,msg,(10,80),(260,-1),wx.ALIGN_CENTER)


    def option2(self,event):
        box2=wx.MessageDialog(None,self.pin,'Current PIN',wx.OK)
        answer2=box2.ShowModal()
        box2.Destroy()

    def option3(self,event):
        box3=wx.TextEntryDialog(None,'Type...','','...here')
        if box3.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            answer3=box3.GetValue()
            self.pin=answer3

    def closewindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

    def clear(self,event):
        self.output.Clear()






if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=main(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you push the button (method `option1`) you create a **new** overlapping TextCtrl. You should have created in the constructor and just change the text in the method.

1) Just call `self.output.Clear()` at the beginning of the `option1` method.

2)

```
clipdata = wx.TextDataObject()
clipdata.SetText("Text here")
wx.TheClipboard.Open()
wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipdata)
wx.TheClipboard.Close()
```

Comment: So far I'm only creating small seperate parts so I'll start this one from scratch. (I got a little in over my head this time)
Thank you very much.